# 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.' in TFS for DWH project

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, data-warehouse

can someone please help me to undestand this error from Visual Studio Team Foundation Server while deploying a release for our DWH project?
[image]

It states

```
##[error]Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
##[error]At C:\TfsData\Build\_work\23df65eef\DWH_CI_TEST\Artifacts\Staging.Database\Scripts\TFS-CI\SSRSdeployment_DEV.ps1:289
ch
```

I guess there might me some issue with references?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: We’d need to see the powershell file that the error is referencing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full stack trace as text. Also, it seems that a path is empty `$rdlFile.FullName`.

Comment: Can you share your build definition?